# How to use specific member of a font-family in xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a font family (human readable name is "Helvetica LT Std") that has several "member" fonts that I want to use in my XSL-FO (such as fo:block and fo:inline) document. Some of the names of the "member" fonts are:

- "Helvetica LT Std Condensed" (file name is: HELVETICALTSTD COND_0.OTF)
- "Helvetica LT Std Bold Condensed Oblique" (file name is:
  HELVETICALTSTD BOLDCONDOBL_0.OTF)

If I use `<fo:block font-family='Helvetica LT Std'>Test</fo:block>`, then I will use the right font family (or I think I am), but I don't know how to direct my FO processor to use the right "member" font. How can I tell it to use "Helvetica LT Std Condensed" (for example)?

I am using Antenna House XSL Formatter 6.2 MR4.

Comment: Refer to the documentation http://www.antennahouse.com/XSLsample/help/V60/AHFormatterV60.en.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I obviously did not read it closely enough before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like CSS, there's separate properties for:

- font-family (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-family)
- font-weight (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-weight)
- font-style (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-style)
- font-stretch (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font-stretch)

and the shorthand 'font' property (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#font) for setting multiple properties at once.

So you can select the right "member" font using either multiple properties or the right keywords/values in the 'font' property (though you don't need to set properties with values that are going to be the same as the initial/inherited value, of course).

Comment: Ah thank you. The part I was missing was how those properties are used for selecting the "member" font rather than using the "member" font name as the value for @font-family. (I obviously did not RTM closely enough.) So far the simplest way I've found to find the way those properties combine to select the right font is by defining an alias in my font-config.xml file and then inspecting the AreaTree for those values. Is there an easier way? (I gave TTFDump a quick whirl and I see that one can find the weightClass and I assume font-style="italic" is true if the italicAngle has a non-zero value)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, but I just came across your comment again.  If you are using the AH Formatter GUI, you can hover your mouse over some text to see a 'tooltip' that includes the font information.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf66/ahf-gui.html#tooltip